# Executing multiple awk commands in one file

Tags: unix, awk

I am trying to extract lines from a file and save the output to a new file.

I have been using the code:

```
cat datafile | awk -f pullhh.txt > fuel
```

where the file `pullhh.txt` contains the code `/FUELHH/`

I want to extract lines containing the word `FUELHH` and save them to a file and then also extract lines containing `FUELINST` and save them to a separate file.

Is there a way to do this having both commands in the `pullhh.txt` file?

Comment: You don't need a script file at all, just write `awk '/FUELHH/ || /FUELINST/' datafile > fuel` as glenn suggests

Comment: @terdon: what about `and save them to a separate file`?

Comment: @sparkie, indeed, missed that, thanks, see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: to print to separate files:

```
/FUELHH/   {print > "fuelhh.txt"}
/FUELINST/ {print > "fuelinst.txt"}
```

Since `pullhh.txt` is actually an awk script, the `txt` extension is misleading. Use something like `extract_lines.awk` and then:

```
awk -f extract_lines.awk datafile
```

Comment: diverting to 2 different files (as required by the thread opener) is not addressed by this solution

Answer (score 1):

since you want to divert the output to 2 different files I suggest the following (to execute  via `-f` awk option).

```
BEGIN {
    while (getline line < "datafile" > 0) {
        if (match(line, "FUELHH"))   print line > "file1"
        if (match(line, "FUELINST")) print line > "file2"
    }
}
```

shorter solution:

```
{
    if (match($0, "FUELHH"))   print > "file1"
    if (match($0, "FUELINST")) print > "file2"
}
```

Comment: Why are you putting this in a BEGIN block?

Comment: @terdon: because I'm so used to that:-) In larger scripts I often have to process many input files sequentially. The simple method isn't feasible there. Nevertheless I added a shorter solution - thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a one liner, no script file is necessary:

```
awk '/FUELHH/{print > "fuelhh.txt"}/FUELINST/{print}' datafile > fuelinst.txt
```